# Getting a child div to trigger overflow in the parent

Tags: html, css

I have a container div (id = #game) that is designed to take up 90% of the page width at all times, and I want to put a large div (id = #game_div) of fixed size inside it. Now naturally on smaller screens, this inner div (1024 X 768) won't fit in the container, so I want it to overflow with scroll bars.

Here's the css:

```
#game
{
    max-width: 90%;
    overflow: scroll;
    padding: 20px;
}

#game_div
{
    width: 768px;
    height: 1024px;
}
```

When I hide the inner div, the outer div appears like this, which correctly uses 90% of the screen:
[image]

However when I add the inner div, it *pushes the size of the parent to off the screen instead of triggering overflow* (those scroll bars are the window scroll bars not the parent div's scroll bars):
[image]

How can I stop the inner div from causing the parent to expand, and instead force it to trigger overflow in the parent so I can use those scrollbars?

Comment: Have you tried relatively positioning the elements? That *might* work..

Comment: @JoshCrozier What do you mean by that? Relative positioning is for sibling elements, not child/parent elements isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

that is because the body overflow is being triggered and you can't see the right side of the `#game` div . by default the `body` tag has `overflow:visible` so you can disable that by

```
body{
overflow:hidden;
}
```

if you only want to hide the body overflow hidden if the main window is smaller than  `width: 768px;` then add a media query `min-size` or you can trigger it via javascript like `$("body").css("overflow", "hidden");`

here is a trial [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YNp32/)